# How to create multi-word document-term matrix?

Tags: python, tokenize, text-classification

I have previously built a text classification model using `NLTK`.
Now I need to build a similar model but this time I have to use multi-worded tokens instead of one word tokens. 
Also my input data cotains already extracted features (historical data) and multi-worded tokens from the documents to be classified.
I don't have the original data.

I intend to buld a Document Phrase Matrix and then a classifier.

PS: NLTK allows ngram tokenizer, but here I don't have the source data. I am only give multi worded tokens.

**Input:**

```
features = ['food security','indigenous groups','national forest','wood forest']

Doc1 = ['food security','indigenous groups','wood forest']

Doc2 = ['national forest','wood forest']

Doc3 = ['tree products', 'forest resources']

Doc4 = ['local population']

Doc5 = []
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Features | food security | indigenous groups | national forest | wood forest |
+----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Doc1     |             1 |                 1 |               0 |           1 |
| Doc2     |             0 |                 0 |               1 |           1 |
| Doc3     |             0 |                 0 |               0 |           0 |
| Doc4     |             0 |                 0 |               0 |           0 |
| Doc5     |             0 |                 0 |               0 |           0 |
+----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

From here on I plan to build a classifier.

right now my plan is to convert these multi worded tokens / features to single words by replacing ' ' with '_'. 'food security' becomes 'food_security'. But I know this is very bad way of doing it.  I am looking for any better methods

Comment: this sounds like the word tokenizer from nltk is the wrong method to use in this context. In which data structure do you need it?

Comment: @hansaplast no, I can't use it here because I don't the source data (collection of documents). I only have multi word features (based on historical data) and keywords (from the documents that need to classified based on extracted features).

Comment: so can the table below in any format? could e.g. a [numpy bitarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) and a dict which translates from phrase to bit-array-index?

Comment: @hansaplast Not a problem as long as we can convert it back to martrix/dataframe format later.

Comment: can you point me to the matrix/dataframe you need to work with in the end? ideally you would not need to do two conversions but just one

Comment: @hansaplast it's should look like the optput i have mentioned here